# How can I increase To The Moon's default resolution?

Tags: to-the-moon

I recently picked up *To The Moon* while it was on sale on Steam.

After owning it for a week and not touching it, I finally decided to fire it up and see how it was. To my dismay, the window was *tiny*! I didn't see an options menu to speak of, and have tried manually adjusting the window size; nothing worked. So, I'm stuck playing in this tiny window:

[image]

**Is there any way to fix this?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to customise the resolution, you have two options really - windowed mode in a 640x480 window or fullscreen mode (by toggling it with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) which will stretch the image to the size of your desktop resolution.

This means that one option could be to change your desktop resolution to the resolution you wish to run the game at and then run it fullscreen, but if you have a monitor with an aspect ratio other than 4:3 then you'll experience blurring and scaling (so the moon won't be round, etc).

<sup>[Source](http://freebirdgames.com/forum/index.php?topic=3360.0) | [Source](http://freebirdgames.com/forum/index.php?topic=3520.0) | [Source](http://uk.gamespot.com/forums/topic/28957073/to-the-moon)</sup>

Comment: `or fullscreen mode (by toggling it with ALT+ENTER) which will stretch the image to the size of your desktop resolution` Not necessarily -- only if your monitor and video drivers are configured to stretch the image.

Comment: Just to be a pedant, it doesn't stretch the game to your monitor size, it drops your monitor resolution to 640x480 (try taking a screenshot while it's running to see what I mean). For all that, much better than windowed and still and epic game

Answer (score 2):

When running in windowed mode, you could use the magnifier (windows key and +) to enlarge the screen.

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> and select **Reduce screen flickering** for a better experience.

Loads of technical information about the game on [this](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/To_the_Moon) page.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually resize the window if you give it the configuration option (I'm looking at the DRM-free version here) `winResizable=true` in the file mkxp.conf .  I haven't found a way to change the default resolution yet.